# Passando dado da view para o controller com Viewbag/ como passar valor do script jquery para uma viewbag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho  o seguinte trecho

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-left:15px">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="Empreendimento" class="form-control">
                            <label>EmpreendimentoId</label>
                            @*@ViewBag.Empreendiment=EmpreendimentoId*@
 <input type="text" id="Empreendimentoid">
```

**js**

```
/*@ INICIALIZA SELECT @*/
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("#Empreendimento").select2({
        language: "pt-BR",
        containerCssClass: ':all:',
        theme: "bootstrap",
        ajax: {
            url: "/Empreendimentos/GetEmpreendimentos",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    search: params.term,
                    page: params.page || 1,
                    limit: 12,
                    sortBy: "text",
                    direction: "asc"
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        placeholder: 'Buscar Empreendimento...'
    });
});


$('#Empreendimento').on('', function (e) {





});
/*@ ADICIONA EVENTO PARA PREENCHER CAMPOS AO SELECIONAR UM EMPREENDIMENTO @*/
$("#Empreendimento").on('select2:select', function (e) {
    $("#nome").val(e.params.data.text);
    $("#contrato").val(e.params.data.Contrato_Empreendimento);
    $("#ordem").val(e.params.data.OrdemDeServico);
      var x = $("#Empreendimento").val();
    function qualquer() {
        return x;
    }
    document.getElementById("Empreendimentoid").value = x;
```

e eu quero passar esse valor pra o controller atraves de uma viewbag ou semelhantes.... como fazer?

obs: quero passar o valor que esta dentro de empreendimentoId pro controller

Editação:

Eu sei que tudo é feito por http,  inclusive por causa do model binder, isso deveria esta passando para o post, com o valor do empreendimentoId, mas ele sempre vem vazio.

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]


 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Laudo laudo)
{

        ViewBag.LaudoId = new SelectList(db.CaracterizacaoRegiaoResidencias, "LaudoId", "LaudoId", laudo.LaudoId);
        ViewBag.LaudoId = new SelectList(db.CaracterizacaoResidencias, "LaudoId", "LaudoId", laudo.LaudoId);
        ViewBag.LaudoId = new SelectList(db.ComposicaoUnidadeResidencias, "LaudoId", "LaudoId", laudo.LaudoId);
        ViewBag.LaudoId = new SelectList(db.Finalizacaos, "LaudoId", "LaudoId", laudo.LaudoId);
        ViewBag.EmpreendimentoId = new SelectList(db.Empreendimentoes, "EmpreendimentoId", "Contrato_Empreendimento", laudo.EmpreendimentoId);




        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Laudoes.Add(laudo);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

       return View(laudo);
    }
```

Comment: Para você passar qualquer valor da View para a Controller precisará fazer uma requisição para o servidor, seja ela GET, POST, PUT ou DELETE... Também não consegui entender o que está tentando representar com o trecho de JS, além de não fazer sentido, ele não tem relação alguma com a pergunta.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, esse é o trecho, a parte significante do exemplo eu não postei o codigo completo, obrigado pela informação, eu vou editar a pergunta com o meu problema direitnho, pq eu ja tentei usar o modelbinder pra enviar no no formulario e não consegui, por isso fiz essa pergunta.

Comment: @RaphApresentacao quando comecei utilizei esse artigo no site do Macoratti: http://www.macoratti.net/15/05/mvc_ajax.htm vale muito a pena você dar uma lida e tentar reproduzir para entender como funciona ;)

Comment: Sua controller espera um `Laudo`, a sua view apresenta apenas o input `<input type="text" id="Empreendimentoid">`... Não sei se no seu caso isso já contempla os parâmetros de entrada... Depois, para que o bind da `Empreendimentoid`, seu input precisa apresentar o atributo `name="Empreendimentoid"`

Comment: Foi isso que reparei depois, que o bind age por name e nao id

Comment: Resolvido então?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para receber os valores da sua `View` na `Controller`, você precisa declarar o atributo `name`. O atributo `id` serve para o javascript e css, se o input não tiver um name definido ele não será incluído no FormData, não vai ser postado para o servidor e, por consequência, não será recebido na controller.

```
<input type="text" id="Empreendimentoid" name="Empreendimentoid" />
```